# R: how to read multiple csv files with column name in row n and select certain columns from the file and add file name to the file as a new column?

Tags: r

I have 100 csv files in the same folder, let's say the path="D:\Data".

For each file I want to:

Step 1. read the file from row 12 since the column names are at row 12;

Step 2. select certain columns from the file, let's say the colname I want to keep
are "Date","Time","Value";

Step 3. add the file name to the file as a new column, for example, I want to
save file1 of which name is "example 1.csv" as file1$Name="example 1.csv",
and similarly, save file2 of which name is "example 2.csv" as
file2$Name="example 2.csv", etc...

So far we got 100 new files with 4 columns "Date","Time","Value","Name". Then finally rbind all the 100 new files together.

I have no idea how to code these steps all together in R. So anyone can help? Thanks very much for your time.

---

##### update

Due the complicated data structure in my data, it always return errors by using the sample code in answers. The ideas behind the code were correct, but somehow I could only solve the problem by using the code as below. I believe there would be more elegant way to modify my code instead of using loop.

```
# set up working directory
setwd("D:/Data")

library(data.table) 
files <- list.files(path ="D:/Data", pattern = ".csv")

# read and save each file as a list of data frame in temp
temp <- lapply(files, read.csv, header = TRUE, skip=11, sep = "\t", fileEncoding="utf-16")

seq_along(temp) # the number of files is 112

## select columns "Date","Time","Value" as a new file, 
## and attach the file name as a new column to each new file, 
## and finally row bind all the files together 

temp2=NULL
for(i in 1:112) {
  dd=cbind(File=files[i],temp[[i]][,c("Date","Time","Value")])
  temp2=rbind(temp2,dd)
}
```

Comment: Read the online doc for `read.csv`.  Particularly the `skip` argument.  Write a function to read one file.  Use `lapply` to apply this function to your list of file names.  `dplyr::bind_rows` has a `.id` argument that will allow you to add the file names to each data frame in the list returned by `lapply` and will bind the data frames together.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
list_of_files <- list.files(path <- "D:/Data/", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list_of_files %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
            readr::read_csv(.,
                     skip = 12, 
                     col_names = TRUE
            ) %>% 
            select(Date, Time, Value) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.character(Date)) %>% 
# Alternatively you could use the .id argument in map_dfr for the filename
            mutate(filename = match(.x, list_of_files)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe the idea was correct, but it returned me errors when I run the code: Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$Date` <character> and `..2$Date` <date>. It seems like the column types were inconsistent. So how could I fix this problem?

Comment: I make a edit in the code :) and yes for some files it reads them in as date class and some as character class, which cannot be combined in one column

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very neatly with `vroom`. It can take a list of files as an argument rather than having to do each separately, and add the filename column itself:

```
library(vroom)

vroom(files, skip = 11, id = 'filename', col_select = c(Date, Time, Value, filename))
```

Comment: Instead of using `select()` after reading in all of the data, you can use `col_select()` inside vroom to only read in those specific columns (ref [the docs](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/#column-selection))

Comment: That's a much better option @jared_mamrot, I've edited to use this.

Comment: It would also be good to add `list_of_files <- list.files(path = "D:/Data/", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)` or `list_of_files <- fs::dir_ls("D:/Data/", glob = "*.csv")` to show where "list_of_files" comes from

Comment: Thanks a lot, Richard and @jared_mamrot. I still have question about the id part. I have file names as "example 1.csv", "example 2.csv",etc...So how to set up the id with multiple file names? Also, should I get the files, by using: files <- list.files(path <- "D:/Data/", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE) and apply it as vroom (files, ...) ?

Comment: Using `list.files()` as you say will work. The id part should work automatically for you: `'filename'` is just what to name the column, and the column will be filled in automatically by vroom.

Comment: Also if the column names are too complicated, can I use the column index numbers in the col_select()? But then I am not sure how to add the 'filename' to it.

Comment: It returns error as: Error in `stop_subscript()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Date` doesn't exist.

Comment: You should be able to use a vector of column indices in `col_select = `. The error is complaining that the data you imported does not have a column called `Date`. Check that there is a 'Date' column and that you are skipping the right number of lines to get the column headings.

Comment: For example, if I have 8 columns in the file, and I want to select  2,3,6 and filename, then it would be col_select(c(2,3,6,9)), right?

Comment: The colnames do locate at line 12 in the csv file, and Date column does exist. The error also showed: Files must end with a newline. So anything I should fix with it?

Comment: It would be `col_select = c(2,3,6,9)` not `col_select(c(2,3,6,9))`. It is difficult to help without having the data ourselves. Are you able to share some sample data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246857/discussion-between-robin-and-richard-berry).